# I got this error while cloning and running a .NET project frm github

Tags: c#, .net, web

i'm not a proffessional programmer in C# an .NET, i tried to clone and run this git repository and i got this error! [image]

Comment: Did you try following the link the message gave you?

Comment: The message says everything: You need to install the .NET 3.1 runtime.

Comment: @canton7 i'm trying right now!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the correct version of .NET installed.
You need the 3.1 runtime but you currently only have 5.0.13 and 6.01

You can download the version you need here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1

or you can install it with the visual studio installer.